# How do I connect to geoserver on my system using java code?

Tags: geoserver

I am writing the following code...
But i am getting an error as...

java.io.FileNotFoundException: http:// localhost:8080/geoserver/
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1613)
    at Try.main(Try.java:25)

Am i doing it right? I am new at this geoserver as well as client server coding...

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class Try{

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception{

        URL hp= new URL ("http://localhost:8080/geoserver");


        try {

            URL myURL = new URL("http://localhost:8080/geoserver/");

            URLConnection myURLConnection = myURL.openConnection();

            myURLConnection.connect();

            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader (myURLConnection.getInputStream()));

            String inputLine;

            while((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null )
            {
                System.out.println(inputLine);

            }

            in.close();

        }
        catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println("Into CATCH");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }           
    }
}
```

Comment: is geoserver running? what happens if you just try to connect to http://localhost:8080?

Comment: Yes geoserver running... if i connect to localhost:8080 through the above code i get ORACLE DATABASE 10g EXPRESS EDITION LICENSE AGREEMENT Letter as ouput page...

Answer (score 2):

You have Oracle XE installed on your system that's taking port 8080, you either move GeoServer on a different port, or move the XE admin UI to another port

Comment: How do i change my geoserver port? I tried this http://docs.huihoo.com/geoserver/1.6.0/67652.html but it doesnt work.... it still works on 8080

Comment: reinstall and select port 8088 in the install settings